# How to perform ajax GET from an ajax POST in flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I want to perform two ajax methods, `POST` and `GET`, on a list of buttons. The button clicked holds the value `index` and should pass it to the method triggered by ajax GET.

I am able to do the `GET` part that calls `'/download_file'` but I have not been able to create an ajax `POST` that can pass the `index` value to method.

Here my function inside `app.py` (simplified) :

```
@app.route('/download_file',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def save_doc():
    index = request.form.get('index')
    print(index)
```

And my html :

```
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
            $(function() {
              $('a#test').bind('click', function() {
                $.getJSON('/download_file',
                    function(data) {
                  //do nothing
                });
                return false;
              });
            });

    </script>
    <div>
        <h1>messages list</h1>
        <div>
            <ol>
                {%for index, message in enumerate(messages)%}
                    <li>{{ index }}{{ message.date }}-{{message.name}}</li>
                    <form>
                         <a href="" id=test><button id="btn" value="{{ index }}" class='btn btn-default'>Download</button></a>
                    </form>
                {%endfor%}
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: why don't you send it all in one requests - `GET` or `POST` ? I

Comment: BTW: to receive `POST` you need `@app.route('/download_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`. As default `route` accepts only `GET` requests.

Comment: `var index = $('a#test').attr("value")` ?

Comment: inside funciton you have to use `request.form.get("variable")` (if you send `variable` in body) or `request.args.get("variable")` (if you send it as `url?variable=...`)

Comment: I'm pretty new to flask so this is a bit confusing, but how do I send it all in one request? I've updated my code

Comment: you can use [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to send `POST` and you can send `index` in url `/download_file?index=...`

Comment: BTW: you can bind it directly to `<button>` and you don't need `<a>` for this.

Comment: BTW: what do you want to POST ? I don't see any `<input>` in `<form>` for data to upoload on server.

Comment: I want to post the index clicked from the list

Comment: Frankly, you could send it in url `/download_file?index=...` and use `GET` for this - but some people want to hide information in `POST` so I created answer which send `index` in `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you don't need `<a>`. You can bind `click` to `<button>`

You don't have to send `GET`. You can get `index` from button and send it in `POST` using `$.post()`.

```
    $('button').bind('click', function() {

        value = $(this).attr('value');

        $.post('/download_file'

            {'index': value},

            function(data) {
              //do nothing
            });

        return false;
    });
```

---

Minimal working example

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = [
        {'date': 'dateA', 'name': 'nameA'},
        {'date': 'dateB', 'name': 'nameB'}
    ]
    return render_template_string('''
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
          $('button').bind('click', function() {
            value = $(this).attr('value');
            $.post('/download_file', //?index=' + value,
                {'index': value},
                function(data) {
                  alert("Response: " + data);
                });
            return false;
          });
        });
    </script>
    <div>
        <h1>messages list</h1>
        <div>
            <ol>
                {%for message in messages %}
                    <li>{{ message.date }} - {{message.name}}</li>
                    <form>
                         <button id="btn" value="{{ loop.index0 }}" class='btn btn-default'>Download</button></a>
                    </form>
                {%endfor%}
            </ol>
        </div>        
    </div>
</body>''', messages=data)


@app.route('/download_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def save_doc():
    print('method:', request.method)
    index = request.form.get('index')
    print('form["index"]:', index)
    #print('args:', request.args)
    #print('form:', request.form)
    #print('data', request.data)
    #print('files', request.files)
    return "Server: " + str(index)

app.run() #debug=True
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves almost everything. Last question, where is the `data` argument coming from inside `function(data) {
                  alert("Response: " + data);
                });`

Comment: it is data which flask sends as response `return "Server: " + str(index)` - jQuery assings it to variable `data` which is used in `function(data) {...}`